# validate data and then return resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to return resolve() if all the fields is valid otherwise return reject?

```
let validateData = (data) => {
    let fields = [
        'Field1',
        'Field2',
        'Field3'
    ];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fields.forEach(field => {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                // resolve if all matched
            } else {
                //reject?
            }
        });
    });
}
```

In the main it will have

```
try {
    await validateData(data);
} catch(err) {
    throw new Error(`${err}`);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If any of the fields do not exist on the data object reject as soon as it is found out. If not you can resolve in the end.

```
let validateData = (data) => {
    let fields = [
        'Field1',
        'Field2',
        'Field3'
    ];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fields.forEach(field => {
            if (!data.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                reject();
            }
        });
        resolve();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fields.forEach(field => {
        if (!data.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
            reject();
            return;
        }
    });

    resolve();
});
```

If any of the properties is not valid simply `reject` else if all of them are valid it wont go inside the if statement and it will resolve the promise.

Comment: That `return` is redundant. `forEach` will still proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The error object will contain a description of the validation errors:

```
let validateData = (data) => {
    let fields = [
        'Field1',
        'Field2',
        'Field3'
    ];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let errors = [];
        fields.forEach(field => {
            if (!data.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                errors.push(`ValidationFieldError: ${field}`);
            }
        });

        errors.length ? reject(new Error(errors.join('\n'))) : resolve();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all fields validaton require async operation, you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which will be resolved only if all the fields validation have been resolved.

**E.g.**

```
let validateData = async (data) => {
    let fields = [
        'Field1',
        'Field2',
        'Field3'
    ];

    let fieldsValidatedPromsises = [];


    fields.forEach(field => {
        let validationPromise = new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                // resolve if all matched
            } else {
                //reject?
            }
        });

        fieldsValidatedPromsises.push(validationPromise);
    });

    return Promise.all(fieldsValidatedPromsises).then(function () {
        return true;
    })
    .catch(function () {
        return false;
    });
}

let c = await validateData(data);

if (c) {
    // All fields validation is successful
}
else {
    // One of field validation fails
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way would be

```
let validateData = async (data) => {
    let fields = [
        'Field1',
        'Field2',
        'Field3'
    ];
    let promises = [];
    fields.forEach(field =>
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve) =>
            data.hasOwnProperty(field) ? resolve() : reject())
        )
    );
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
let validateData = async(data) => {
  let fields = [
    'Field1',
    'Field2',
    'Field3'
  ];
  let promises = [];
  fields.forEach(field =>
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve) =>
      data.hasOwnProperty(field) ? resolve() : reject()))
  );
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

async function foo() {
  try {
    await validateData({
      'Field1': 1,
      'Field2': 2,
      'Field3': 3
    });
    console.log('valid here');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Invalid');
  }
}

foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach...

```
let validateData = (data) => {
    let fields = [
        'Field1',
        'Field2',
        'Field3'
    ];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fields.every(field => data.includes(field)) ? resolve() : reject();
    });
}
```